# Counting specific sequences vertically

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I was trying to figure out a simple way to count the sequence of characters in a row, based on a specific condition.

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3xXNI.jpg)

the letter "R" is supposed to be written in only one cell at the whole sheet.

What I want is to count, vertically, how many consecutive "P" I have after i've found a "R" and then, stop counting on, if a different letter than "R" is found.

At the attached image, I would have as a desired output a number 2 (R,P,P,L)

A sequence like R,P,P,P,P,L would have 4 as output

Can you guys help me to think a in a simple logic to work out on this?

Thanks in advance

haven't tried nothing yet

Answer (score 0):

*Assuming no Excel version constraints as per the tags listed in the question*. You can put the following formula in cell `E2`:

```
=LET(A,A1:A9,s,C1,c,C2,sc,SCAN(-1,A,LAMBDA(ac,x,IF(AND(ac=-1,x=s),ac+1,
 IF(AND(ac=0,x=c),ac+1,IF(AND(ac>=0,x<>c),-2,ac))))),SUM(N(sc=1)))
```

or without using `LET`:

```
=SUM(N(SCAN(-1,A1:A9,LAMBDA(ac,x,IF(AND(ac=-1,x=C1),ac+1,IF(AND(ac=0,x=C2),ac+1,
 IF(AND(ac>=0,x<>C2),-2,ac)))))=1))
```

Here is the output:
[image: output]